# Code for CSS only button like this? A different way around this style?

Tags: css, user-interface, animation, transition

Is there a better version of this button or a less laggy one?

I have tried to find this exact type of styled button however I cannot. This is a very poor attempt which needs to be greatly refactored as I didn't think about the correct styling from the start.

Any links or more efficient code would greatly be appreciated

I have seen similar code however its just this exact style of the lines basically being drawn and removed around the button that I would like (this is just a ramble because of the "requirement" to have more of a description than code)

```css
.UnderlineButton { 
 border: none;
 background-color: white;
 position: relative;
 border: 2px solid;
 border-top-color: rgb(255,255,255);
 border-right-color: rgb(255,255,255);
 border-left-color: rgb(255,255,255);
 border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    padding: 10px;
 padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 
 -webkit-animation: UnderlineButton .5s forwards;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes UnderlineButton {
  0%   { 
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   border-right-color: red;
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-top-color: red;
   border-left-color: red;
  }
  19% {
   border-right-color: red;
  }
  20% {
   border-right-color:  rgb(255,255,255);
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-top-color: red;
   border-left-color: red;
  }
  39% {
   border-top-color: red;
  }
  40% {
   border-right-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-top-color:  rgb(255,255,255);
   border-left-color: red;
  }
  59% {
   border-left-color: red;
  }
  60 {
   border-right-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-top-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-left-color:  rgb(255,255,255);
  }
  100% { 
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   border-right-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-top-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-left-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }
 
 .UnderlineButton:hover {
  -webkit-animation: UnderlineButtonHover .5s forwards;
 }
 
 @-webkit-keyframes UnderlineButtonHover {
  0%   {
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   border-right-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-top-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-left-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  }
  20% {
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   border-right-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-top-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-left-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  }
  39% {
   border-right-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  }
  40% {
   border-right-color: red;
   border-left-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-top-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  }
  59% {
   border-top-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  }
  60% {
   border-right-color: red;
   border-top-color: red;
   border-left-color: rgb(255,255,255);
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  }
  79% {
   border-left-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  }
  80% {
   border-right-color: red;
   border-top-color: red;
   border-left-color: red;
   border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  }
  99% {
   border-bottom-color: red;
  }
  100% {
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   border-right-color: red;
   border-bottom-color: red;
   border-top-color: red;
   border-left-color: red;
  }
 }


 .UnderlineButton:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  right: 10%;
  -webkit-animation: UnderlineButtonBefore .5s forwards;
 }
 
  @-webkit-keyframes UnderlineButtonBefore {
   0%   { 
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 2px;
   }
   20% {
    left: 100%;
    right: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 2px;
    top: 100%;
   }
   21% {
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
   }
   40% {
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
   }
   41% {
    top: -2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
   }
   60% {
    top: -2px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
   }
   61% {
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    left: -2px;
    bottom: 0;
   }
   80% {
    top: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 0;
    left: -2px;
    bottom: 0;
   }
   90% {
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
   }
   100% { 
    right: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    bottom: -2px;
    height: 2px;
   }
  }
 
 .UnderlineButton:hover:before {

  -webkit-animation: UnderlineButtonBeforeHover .5s forwards;
 }
 
  @-webkit-keyframes UnderlineButtonBeforeHover {
   0%   { 
    right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
   }
   20% {
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 100%;
   }
   21% {
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    top: 100%;
    
   }
   40% {
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: -2px;
   }
   41% {
    top: -2px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 2px;
    left: 100%;
   }
   60% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    top: -2px;
   }
   61% {
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
   }
   80% {
    height: 100%;
    width: 2px;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
   }
   81% {
    height: 2px;
    width: 2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    top: 100%;
   }
   100% { 
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    height: 2px;
   }
  }
```

```html
<div style="padding: 40px; background-color:rgb(252,252,252);">
  <button class="UnderlineButton">Underline</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?  What's not working the way you expect?

Comment: It looks very laggy, I would like a better version of this button. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: FWIW, not seeing a lag.  Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something of this sort. I had a similar requirement in the past. Just give me a few moments to modify it your requirement. meanwhile please feel free to see if you can do it yourself. I believe you are looking for the transition?

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
  color: #f45e61;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
button::before, button::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
          box-sizing: inherit;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.draw {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s;
  transition: color 0.25s;
}
.draw::before, .draw::after {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.draw::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.draw::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.draw:hover {
  color: #60daaa;
}
.draw:hover::before, .draw:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.draw:hover::before {
  border-top-color: #60daaa;
  border-right-color: #60daaa;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
  transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
.draw:hover::after {
  border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
  border-left-color: #60daaa;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<section class="buttons">
 <button class="draw">Draw</button>
 <section>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is one of the examples I found! However I would like it to animate on the return as well unfortunately. Also a problem I found with the transition is if you move your mouse away during animation you get a glitch-y result where as with the animation forward you don't get this problem.